# How to check if JSON returned any let say rows?

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to get JSON data and add it to rows, but how can i check if **data** is not empty ?

This is what I am trying,

```
$.getJSON(url, {
    startDate: today.getDate(),
    itemCount: 6,
    urlparameter: "http://....
})
.done(function (data) {
        $.each(data.GetwebMethodResult, function (index, item) {
        $("#TableABC").append(FunABC(item.aID, item.b, item.c, item.d, item.e, item.f));
        });

function FunABC(a, b, c, d, e, f) {
    var row =
        "<tr class='Row' onclick=\"AnotherUnrelatedFunction('" + a + "' , '" + b + "', '" + c + "', '" + d + "', '" + e + "', '" + f + "')\">" +
        "   <div class='mr'>" +
        "       <td class='mc mci'>" +
        "           <div class='mcit'>" + a + "</div>" +
        "       </td>" +
        "   </div>" +
        "</tr>";

    return row;
}
```

Comment: I like your variable names ;)

Comment: `data.GetwebMethodResult.length`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/

Comment: @Nouphal.M length is for array not object

Comment: @CustomizedName what about providing your attempt...? What is data returned from $.getJSON, we need to see it...

Comment: @A.Wolff i used this instead http://api.jquery.com/jquery.hasdata/

Answer (score 0):

I used this,

```
$.hasData(data);
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.hasdata/